# How to iterate over childNodes using foreach loop?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Consider the following PHP code

```
<?php

 $html_data = 
 '<html><body>
  <ol>
  <li><strong>Question 1</strong> Answer1</li>
  <li><strong>Question 2</strong> Answer2</li>
  </ol></body></html>';

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html_data);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

  $ols = $xpath->query('//ol');
  $ol = $ols->item(0);
  $lis = $ol->childNodes;

  foreach ($lis as $li) {
    echo $li->firstChild->nodeValue."<br />";
    echo $li->lastChild->nodeValue."<br />";
    //echo $li->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."<br />";
  }
  ?>
```

If I remove the comment on the last line of this code and access the childNodes DOM Object Array, my foreach loop executes only once. However, if I access the same elements using firstChild and lastChild as shown above, I can successfully iterate over all the 'li' tags present.

I can't make any sense of this at all. Is this a bug in PHP?

Comment: What's your PHP version? And could you provide a [minimum working example](http://sscce.org/)? I could not reproduce the problem (see answer)

Comment: Here is the minimum working example. http://codepad.org/cydsaaI2 uses item(0) to print the nodeValue while http://codepad.org/KSjfxiBZ uses firstChild and lastChild. You can see that the code using item is not working while the other is working. When I turn on error reporting, it says that I am trying to access a member function of a non-object. My main question is why item(0) is not working while firstChild or lastChild is working? Are they not supposed to be the same? I am using PHP version 5.3.9, but other versions also have the same problem I think

Comment: @Gowtham: can you edit your post so the "minimum working example" is in the post, and not on codepad. This way, whenever codepad decides to delete your snippet, we can know what was in the missing link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wouldn't suprress your error reporting, you would have seen that you have a fatal error that breaks your script.

In order to work with the **item** method:

```
foreach ($lis as $li) {
  if (method_exists($li->childNodes, 'item')) {
    echo $li->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."<br />";
    // To reproduce the exact output you need this line also. 
    // You need to display the second child (Answer)
    echo $li->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue."<br />";
  }  
}
```

The only difference it was that the first script

```
foreach ($lis as $li) {
  echo $li->firstChild->nodeValue."<br />";
  echo $li->lastChild->nodeValue."<br />";    
  //echo $li->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Only throws **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**, but the scripts continues.

As with method item() it throws a fatal error. **(Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object).** which kills your script.

For more details on how you should iterate on these nodesList (foreach vs. for) read the comments from these pages

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

And you especially have this issue because of the trailing space after the `<li>` tags.

It loops like this: first `<li>` tag, then the space `' ' DOMText` element then the second `<li>` tag then the second `' ' DOMText` element.

On the DOMText element it crashes. You could clear the spaces and it would work.

```
$html_data = '<html><body><ol><li><strong>Question 1</strong> Answer1</li><li><strong>Question 2</strong> Answer2</li></ol></body></html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem (on PHP 5.3.14) with the following code:

```
Interactive shell

php > $xml = <<<XML
<<< > <root>
<<< > <ol>
<<< > <li><strong>Question 1</strong> Answer1</li>
<<< > <li><strong>Question 2</strong> Answer2</li>
<<< > </ol>
<<< > </root>
<<< > XML;
php > $doc = new DOMDocument();
php > $doc->loadXML($xml);
php > $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
php > $ols = $xpath->query('//ol');
php > $ol = $ols->item(0);
php > $lis = $xpath->query('//li', $ol);
php > foreach ($lis as $li) {
php { echo $li->firstChild->nodeValue."<br />";
php { echo $li->lastChild->nodeValue."<br />";
php { echo $li->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."<br />";
php { }
Question 1<br /> Answer1<br />
Question 1<br />
Question 2<br /> Answer2<br />
Question 2<br />
```

As you see, I did not succeed, everything works fine. The only thing I changed was `$lis = $ol->childNodes;` to `$lis = $xpath->query('//li', $ol);` because otherwise I got whitespace text nodes between the `<li>` nodes and the script crashed.

Comment: Check my comment for more info on the question. Also, $lis = $ol->childNodes; and $lis = $xpath->query('//li', $ol); are functionally equivalent, so they will not affect the other parts of the code I think. :)

Comment: In fact, it does: http://codepad.org/OjzGoYet - so it seems to be a side effect of the `childNodes` accessor (maybe something like a shared array pointer? definitely a bug!)

Comment: I just submitted a bug report. You can find it at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64104

Comment: They just closed it - the whitespace nodes that I mentioned were also your problem. You just suppressed the error (I didn't see the error_reporting(0), otherwise I would already have guessed this...)